# Eigen Matrix Decomposition. Jordan not working

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

I am applying Jordan decomposition, but I am uncertain whether matrix $M$ can actually be decomposed.

Let $J=MDM^{-1}$, where $D$ is the diagonalized matrix and $M$ is the matrix made of the eigenvectors.

Jordan decomposition states that if a $N\times N$ matrix has $N$ eigenvalues then matrix $J$ can be decomposed into diagonalized matrix $D$.

The below matrix has $3$ eigenvalues and $3$ columns and rows. However I cannot seem to apply Jacobian decomposition.

$$ J = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1-p & 1-p & 0 \\
    p & 0 & 1-p \\
    0 & p & p \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
with eigenvalues
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \sqrt{p-p^2} & -\sqrt{p-p^2} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
where p is probability between 0 and 1.

The matrix gives eigenvalues $$(p-1)(p-p^2)^2=0$$ which give matrix $M$ which is made up of eigenvectors
$$ M =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    p/(1-p) & \frac{p-1-\sqrt{p-p^2}}{(1-p)} & \frac{\sqrt{ρ-ρ^2}+p-1}{1-p} \\
    \frac{P^2}{(1-p)^2} & \frac{\sqrt{p-p^2}+1-p}{(1-p)(p+\sqrt{p-p^2})} & \frac{\sqrt{p-p^2}-1+p}{(1-p)(p-\sqrt{p-p^2})} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I cannot seem to find the diagonal $M^{-1}$ of the above matrix. This is because there is no $0$ (zero terms).

Does this simply mean that the diagonalized matrix is made of complex terms?

Comment: You appear to be a bit confused about terminology. You’re computing the *Jordan* decomposition, not the Jacobian. The *diagonal* matrix $D$ simply has eigenvalues on the main diagonal. $M^{-1}$ is the *inverse* of $M$. If you’ve computed eigenvectors correctly, $M$ should always be invertible. Note, though, that when $p=0$, your original matrix is singular and $0$ is a repeated eigenvalue. The eigenvectors that you’ve found don’t apply to this situation—notice that some of the denominators become zero.

Comment: Thanks, But then why is the matrix M, not easily diagonalised. 1) The only adjustment I can see is to square row 3 and deduct that from row 2, inorder to get rid of p^2/(1-p)^2 on the far left. Aside from this, there do not seem to be any other adjustment 2) If p=0, that does not yield a diagonalised matrix as intended. Also we are assuming that p is some constant here.

Comment: Why would you want to diagonalize $M$? It represents a basis in which $D$ is diagonal. It’s not the “functional” part of the decomposition.

Comment: Yes, $p$ is a constant, but nowhere in your question have you excluded $p=0$ (or indeed mentioned that $p$ is meant to be a probability $0\le p\le1$).

Comment: P is a probability between 0 and 1 as stated. I am trying to find the closed form formula of p after n days. The Jordan decomposition can provide this.   **Background**: There are 3 cities, K, W and G. When in W, the probability of the tourist going to K=p, G=0 and W= 1-p. When in K, probabilityfor G=p, W=1-p , and k=0. When in G, k=1-p,W= 0 and G=p. Question to answer: Assuming the start of the trip in W, what are the probabilities of being in W, K or G after n days? Using a *closed form formula

Comment: You say no such thing about $p$ in the question. Anyway, If $J=MDM^{-1}$ then $J^n=MD^nM^{-1}$. The interior $M$’s cancel when you multiply it all out. That’s kind of the point of diagonalizing $J$.

Comment: I need to find matrix D which is $$ DM^-1 =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    p/(1-p) & \frac{p-1-\sqrt{p-p^2}}{(1-p)} & \frac{\sqrt{ρ-ρ^2}+p-1}{1-p} \\
    \frac{P^2}{(1-p)^2} & \frac{\sqrt{p-p^2}+1-p}{(1-p)(p+\sqrt{p-p^2})} & \frac{\sqrt{p-p^2}-1+p}{(1-p)(p-\sqrt{p-p^2})} \\
    \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1& 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$ If I do the same adjustments to the matrix on the left as I do the right. Once the matrix on the left is turned to a diagnoal with 1's in it, the matrix on the right will the diagonal of J.

Comment: I understand that J^n = D^n. My query is that the matrix M with the eigen vectors, does not seem to be easily diagonalised. No computations are turning it into a diagonalised matrix. Simultaneous equations are not working out to unique numbers at positions (1,1), (2,2) and (3,3) like other diagonal matrices.

Comment: $M$ *does not get diagonalized*. You’re diagonalizing $J$ by decomposing it into $MDM^{-1}$. The diagonal matrix $D$ has the eigenvalues of $J$ along the main diagonal; the columns of $M$ are the corresponding eigenvectors. Other than inverting $M$ and reassembling everything, that’s all there is to it.

Comment: Are you saying that D is just$$ M =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 &  \\0 & \sqrt{p-p^2} & 0 \\0&0&-\sqrt{p-p^2}\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$